# cURL File Upload - "No File Provided"

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I've been using cURL to successfully interact with a flash-based webpage to extract data, however now I'm trying to use the site's upload functionality to provide a file. For the working requests, I would break down the requests being made by using the Chrome Developer tools and re-create them in cURL. But when I attempt the file upload, I get a JSON response of {"error":"no file provided"}.

The code format extracted from the dev tools which does not work:

```
curl "<URL>" -H "Origin: <URL>" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H     "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----pluploadboundary1454508647816" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: <URL>" -H "X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/20.0.0.286" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "DNT: 1" --data-binary "------pluploadboundary1454508647816"^"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""name"""^"unblock_User.xls"^"------pluploadboundary1454508647816"^"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; filename=""unblock_User.xls"""^"Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel"^
```

I have tried changing it to use the standard --data-binary=@file where @file contains the boundary and the raw binary data of the file, to no avail. The contents of that file are:

> ------pluploadboundary1453998534666
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
>
> unblock_once.xlsx
>
> ------pluploadboundary1453998534666
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="unblock_once.xlsx"
>
> Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
>
> raw data would be here by 'cat'ing the binary file to this section, can I use a path to a file here instead?
>
> ------pluploadboundary1453998534666--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what went wrong here, not knowing what webapp you're working against. However, I just worked through a similar problem and discovered some pitfalls:

- Using the wrong boundary. A request header in your command specified a boundary of "----pluploadboundary1454508647816", but your payload's using "------pluploadboundary1453998534666".
- Using the wrong newlines. The service I worked against only liked Windows-style newlines (\r\n), so I had to run my payload file through unix2dos to get it to match.

After fixing these issues, I got the --data-binary=@file approach to work.